# Can i start gitlab server with fourth lvl domain name?

Tags: url, gitlab

I try to change url for my gitlab server into may local network.
URL must be like
https://gitlab.my-namespace.example.io

But server response with error - 502 Bad Gateway on this URL.
If use IP addres in url (like https://192.168.150.10) - all work correctly ...

Is possible - to use url like this for gitlab server?
Thnx

Comment: Using any particular subdomain shouldn't be a problem. 502 sounds like a bad proxy configuration or the gitlab server behind the proxy is not running. Can you share your relevant gitlab and proxy configurations?

Comment: Thnx!
You are right - problem was with proxy config.
Gitlab work with four lvl subdomain name correctly!